# call function inside a controller with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am looking for a solution to call  a function inside a controller. How could i achieve this.

**State**

```
.state('confirm.registration',
{   url: "/confirm/registration",
   controller:'userController',
   onEnter:'confirmregistration()',
   permissions:{}

})
```

***Controller***

```
$scope.confirmregistration = function(){
//do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. But want to know whether is this the right approach.

**app.js**

```
 .state('confirmregistration',
      {   url: "/confirm/registration/:registrationseed",
          controller:"userController",
          permissions:{}
      })
```

**Controller**

```
if($stateParams.registrationseed){

        console.log($stateParams.registrationseed);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to put `$broadcast` event inside your `onEnter` function, that would be broadcasted in `$rootscope` and that event can be listen by using `$on` inside controller.

**Config**

```
.state('confirm.registration', {
    url: "/confirm/registration",
    controller: 'userController',
    onEnter: function($rootScope, $timeout, $stateParams) {
        //used $timeout to load after controller gets initialized
        //so that $on event should get define before broadcasting
        $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('eventBroadcasted', $stateParams.registrationseed);
        })
    },
    permissions: {}
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.$on('eventBroadcasted', function(event, data) {
    //you can get $route parameter inside data itself
});
```

I think this would be approach, rather than what you are doing. Thanks.

Comment: Hi..Sorry for the late reply. I was  reorganizing my code. And this code didnt work and it taking back to home url. I tried console.log(data) inside controller and it didnt work out.

Comment: does that $timeout gets fire? why it is redirecting to home page.?

Comment: Give me sometime. I shall keep you posted.